# Spring boot rest is adding extra field "target"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-restcontroller, spring-mongodb

```
@Document("user")
public class User
  @Id
  String id;

  @DbRef(lazy=true)
  Group group;
}


@Document("Group")
public class Group{
  @Id
  private String Id;

  private string code;
}
```

JSON User

```
[
  {
    "id": "5922bccbbba56342fc55a73f",
    "group": {
      "id": "5922bccbbba56342fc55a73d",
      "code": "ROLE_ADMIN",
      "target": {
        "id": "5922bccbbba56342fc55a73d",
        "code": "ROLE_ADMIN"
      }
    },

  }
]
```

Problem is i am getting some target attribute in json which is not there in class. Any idea ?

**Update** : `DbRef(lazy = true) add the target attribute`

Comment: Your second class definition looks odd - you haven't given the class a name.

Comment: @PaulNUK : Sorry typo mistake

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55047731/where-do-the-target-properties-in-my-json-serialization-come-from/55048958#55048958