# Where do the "target" properties in my JSON serialization come from?

Tags: json, jackson, mapping, spring-mongodb

I have a spring boot service using MongoDB as a repository for my beans. I added a feature to download a bean in JSON format and upload it on another system (or simply to have a file backup).

I am using the `ObjectMapper` with the `writeValueAsString` method. This all works as expected, except that there are additional properties which aren't part of my bean.

All properties that are defined with `@DBRef` thus pointing to other beans in the MongoDB have a `target` property containing the exact same serialized bean. For ex: I keep track of the user that created the bean through a GUI:

```
{
    createdBy: {
        id: "5bb743feacbd6505304c025e",
        username: "admin",
        target: {
            id: "5bb743feacbd6505304c025e",
            username: "admin"
        }
    }
}
```

Where does this `target` come from and is there a way to get rid of it in the JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Java to JSON serialization with Jackson PTH and Spring Data MongoDB DBRef generates extra target property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48764315/java-to-json-serialization-with-jackson-pth-and-spring-data-mongodb-dbref-genera)

> The Target field is added by Spring Data because it is a lazy
>   collection. So it is like datahandler etc. in Hibernate for JPA.
>
> Option1: To ignore them you just have to add
>   `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "target" })` on class level
>
> ```
> @Document(collection = "song")
> @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "target" })
> public class Song {
>  ...
> }
> ```
>
> Option2: Make the Collection not lazy

Option 3: create your own DBRef serializer as mentioned by [Spring Data Mongo + Lazy Load + REST Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480130/spring-data-mongo-lazy-load-rest-jackson)

Comment: Thanks, didn't find this other question and answer when I was looking for it